# iPhone app name localization (simplified chinese)

Tags: iphone, localization, cjk

I'm attempting to create a localized app, with English and Chinese. I have all the translations in my images. I have localized my image files with the folders `zh_CN.lproj` and they work perfectly in the app.

I have attempted to create an `InfoPlist.strings` file, and declare the `CFBundleDisplayName` (I previously did this with a French localization).

However, the app doesn't seem to be picking the app name from the strings file.

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

I am declaring the bundle name as follows in my strings file.

`CFBundleDisplayName = "my App";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i'd spelt `InfoPlist.strings` as `InfoPList.strings` the capital L was preventing it from working.

Damn case sensitiveness!